# Understanding SQL Server Extended Events: Clarification on "count" Column in "database_transaction_begin" Event

Tags: sql-server, transaction, extended-events

I'm currently working with SQL Server Extended Events and have come across an area I'm finding a bit unclear. I'm trying to understand the various event properties, particularly focusing on the "database_transaction_begin" event.

Specifically, I'm interested in the "count" column of this event. I've been unable to find detailed explanations in the official Microsoft documentation. Could anyone help clarify the purpose of this column?

Additionally, does it serve the same function as @@trancount? Any guidance or reference to official documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance!